# Serialization of a TChan String

Tags: haskell

I have declared the following

```
type KEY = (IPv4, Integer)
type TPSQ = TVar (PSQ.PSQ KEY POSIXTime)
type TMap = TVar (Map.Map KEY [String])

data Qcfg = Qcfg { qthresh :: Int, tdelay :: Rational, cwpsq :: TPSQ, cwmap :: TMap, cw
chan :: TChan String } deriving (Show)
```

and would like this to be serializable in a sense that Qcfg can either be written to disk or be sent over the network. When I compile this I get the error

```
No instances for (Show TMap, Show TPSQ, Show (TChan String))
      arising from the 'deriving' clause of a data type declaration
    Possible fix:
      add instance declarations for
      (Show TMap, Show TPSQ, Show (TChan String))
      or use a standalone 'deriving instance' declaration,
           so you can specify the instance context yourself
    When deriving the instance for (Show Qcfg)
```

I am now not quite sure whether there is a chance at all to serialize my TChan although all individual nodes in it are members of the show class.

For `TMap` and `TPSQ` I wonder whether there are ways to show the values in the `TVar` directly (because it does not get changed, so there should no need to lock it) without having to declare an instance that does a `readTVar` ?

Comment: ...what exactly did you want to happen when you deserialize a `TChan` from the network and read from it? Do more network access to contact the server you got the `TChan` from...?? What does it mean to serialize a `TChan` to _disk_???

Comment: @DanielWagner VERY good comment, ideally when it is revived I can do a `do m <- atomically $ readTChan mtch return (Just m)`I know, I could put the nodes/strings in the TChan in a list as intermediary structure but maybe there are more ways.

Comment: Okay, I know the API you want: you want `TChan`'s API. But what do you want to *happen* when you use that API? What should happen when you read from a `TChan` you got from disk? Should it somehow revive the program that wrote that file and ask it for input? Travel back in time? What if I moved the hard drive to a different machine in the meantime, or shared the file on BitTorrent... should it crowdsource the answer? If you write to the deserialized `TChan`, who gets the message? What, exactly, are you expecting to happen here?

Comment: I'd like to add: I know the questions above sound adversarial, but I'm really just trying to help you ask a better question. If you tell us a bit more about what you're trying to do, we can give more targeted, helpful advice about how to do it.

Comment: @DanielWagner In my case I use TChan as a pure data store where only the FIFO data in it is interesting to me. Nothing is interesting to me that had been surrounding the TChan by the time it had been created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understood your comments to mean that you want to serialize the **contents** of the `TVar` and not the `TVar` itself.

There is only one way to extract the value from a `TVar`, and that's `readTVar`:

```
readTVar :: TVar a -> STM a
```

... which you can do in the `IO` monad using `atomically`:

```
atomically . readTVar :: TVar a -> IO a
```

`TChan` is more tricky, though, since you can't inspect the contents without flushing out the entire `TChan`.  This is doable, even if wastefully, by inspecting the entire contents as a single `STM` action and then reinserting them all.  If this is what you choose to do, it would also eventually require being run in the `IO` monad.

This means you won't be able to derive a `Show` instance for it, since `Show` expects a pure computation that converts it to a `String`, and not one residing in the `IO` monad.

However, there's no reason you have to use the `Show` class.  You can just define a custom function to serialize your data type in the `IO` monad.  Also, it's generally not advisable to use `Show` for serialization purposes since:

- Some of your data types (like `PSQ`) have no `Read` instance
- It's a pain in the butt to define `Read` instances in general
- String representations are very space-inefficient

So I would recommend you use a proper serialization library like `binary` or `cereal` to do serialization and deserialization.  These convert data types to a binary representation, and they make it very easy to define encoders and decoders.

However, even those libraries only accept instances for pure conversions and not operations in the `IO` monad, so what you must do is factor your serialization into a two-step process:

1. Extract the contents of your `TVar`s in the `IO` monad.
2. Serialize the contents (along with the rest of your data-type) using `cereal`/`binary`.

There is still one last caveat, which is that not all of your data types have `Binary` instances (assuming we use the `binary` package), but fortunately lists do have a `Binary` instance, so a convenient work-around is to just convert your data type to a list (using `toList` and serialize the list.  Then, when you deserialize the list, you use `fromList` to recover your original type.

So the following function will do all of that (using `binary`):

```
serializeQcfg file (Qcfg qthresh tdelay cwpsq cwmap cwchan) = do
    -- Step 1: Extract contents of concurrency variables
    psq    <- atomically $ readTVar cwpsq
    myMap  <- atomically $ readTVar cwmap
    myChan <- atomically $ entireTChan cwchan
    -- Step 2: Encode the extracted data
    encodeFile file (qthresh, tdelay, toList psq, myMap, myChan)
```

Edit: Actually, it's probably better to combine all the atomic transactions into a single transaction as Daniel pointed out, so you would actually do:

```
serializeQcfg file (Qcfg qthresh tdelay cwpsq cwmap cwchan) = do
    -- Step 1: Extract contents of concurrency variables
    (psq, myMap, myChain) <- atomically $ (,,) <$> readTVar cwpsq
                                               <*> readTVar cwmap
                                               <*> entireTChan cwchan
    -- Step 2: Encode the extracted data
    encodeFile file (qthresh, tdelay, toList psq, myMap, myChan)
```

I left out the implementation of `entireTChan`, which would basically flush the `TChan` to inspect the entire contents and then reload it again, but its type signature would be something like:

```
entireTChan :: TChan a -> STM [a]
```

I also left out the deserialization implementation, but I think if you understand the above example and take the time to learn how to use the `binary` or `cereal` packages you should be able to figure it out easily enough.

Comment: Only for my comprehension. In this example psq, myMap and my Chan would be an instance of [what] ???

Comment: @JFritsch They would be an instance of `Binary` (or `Serializable`, if you use the `cereal` library.  The `Binary` class then automatically derives the instance for `(,,,,)` based on the `Binary` instances for each component.

Comment: Pretty much what I was going to suggest once I read JFritsch's responses, too, so +1 for that. Only comment here is that you probably want to put the `readTVar`s and `entireTChan` in the same transaction -- that is, you probably want a consistent snapshot of the concurrent state. `(psq,myMap,myChan) <- atomically $ liftM3 (,,) (readTVar cwpsq) (readTVar cwmap) (entireTChan cwchan)` or similar.

Comment: @DanielWagner Great suggestion.  I updated it, but leaving the original just for comparison.